# Corner radius makes the image vanish

Tags: swiftui

I was experimenting with swiftUI and i found out that `cornerRadius` attributes makes my image disappear.

```
Image(uiImage: content.image)
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
    .frame(width: 60, height: 40)
    .cornerRadius(3)
```

Is there something wrong with the code here ?
I want my image to be resizable, fill the whole view, have a dimension of 60x40 and a cornerRadius of 3.

Thanks for your help, if you know what's wrong :)

XCode: 12.1 (12A7403)

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this result in Xcode 12.1.  Which version of Xcode are you using.  Are you able to reproduce it if this is the only View in your `body`?

Comment: Xcode 12.1 (12A7403)
And i get the same in just the view in body. But it might be something wrong with my install then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem and I think it is either a bug, or a something new that came with Xcode 12.1, because it was working perfectly a few weeks back. I did try a lot of ways to put the .cornerRadius() but it always resulted in the Image vanishing. This is my final solution, but I do believe .cornerRadius() would be better here. I hope it will help you! The color of the stroke will need to be the color of your background.

```
Image("MyImage")
     .resizable()
     .frame(width: 19, height: 19, alignment: .center)
     .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
           .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 3.3)
     )
```

Comment: Quite weird, i wasn't sure if i had it working previously but that's what i thought. Anyway, this worked perfectly, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I have met similar problems. When I set the cornerRadius for a view on simulator, the view disappear. However, when running on the real device, the view shows up. I think it is a bug of Xcode, you may test on real device to see your view.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I worked around this.

I made an equivalent of ImageView with UIKit.

```swift
struct FixImageView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let image: UIImage
    let contentMode: UIView.ContentMode

    final class Coordinator: NSObject {}

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIImageView {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
        view.image = image
        view.contentMode = contentMode
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIImageView, context: Context) {
        uiView.image = image
        uiView.contentMode = contentMode
    }
}
```

You can use it just like a normal SwiftUI's Image.

```swift
@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
    FixImageView(image: image, contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)
        .cornerRadius(20)
}
```

If you're wondering why the the compression priority is low, [Tomas Linhart explains:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59745779/8639572)

```
SwiftUI uses the compression resistance priority and the content hugging priority to decide what resizing is possible.

If you want to resize a view below its intrinsic content size, you need to reduce the compression resistance priority.
```